# Preg Match Return Two Word in Array Position

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am trying to extract all words of a .txt file that contants this structure %HOUSE% %CAR%

I am using Preg_match and It´s works but when I have in the same line two words the array return in one position the two words that are in the same line

```
$rawContent = file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); 
$content = implode(" ",$rawContent);    
preg_match_all("/%.*%/",$content,$arrMatches");

Array ( [0] => %HOSTNAME% [1] => %INTERFAZ_LAN% [2] => %IP_LAN% %MASK_LAN% [3] => %ID_INTERFACE_WAN% )
```

In Position [2] there are two word for example
I think that is a problem of my preg match expression I need to add some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, regular expressions using the `*` character will be "greedy", meaning it will match as many characters as possible. In this case, the expression `.*` is matching `IP_LAN% %MASK_LAN`.

To change this bevavior to non-greedy, that is to match as few characters as possible, add a question mark after the asterisk, so your pattern becomes `/%.*?%/`.

Alternatively, you can change your approach and, rather than match *any* character any number of times, match *anything except the percentage sign* any number of times: `/%[^%]*%/`.

Comment: Thanks so much this was the problem I try to add "?" and It´s works thanks